# Syntax error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-error

I've the following code:

```
as.controller('Marketing', function ($scope, $http, $upload) {
  $scope.url = "partials/result.php";   //php-filen
  $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
    var file = $files[0];
    if (file.type.indexOf('image') == -1) {
      $scope.error = 'image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.'
    }
    if (file.size > 2097152) {
      $scope.error = 'File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
    }
    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
      url: upload.php
      data: {fname: $scope.fname},
      file: file,
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // file is uploaded successfully
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}


});
```

When I try to run this, I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
```

I can't find the problem. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: I think you should use a good editor. that will help you find simple syntax errors. sublime text may be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotations marks and a trailing comma on the line `url: upload.php`, and an extra comma after `file: file,`.

It should be

```
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    url: "upload.php",
    data: {fname: $scope.fname},
    file: file
}).success ...
```

Comment: I have changed it to url: 'partials/result.php', but now I get this message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

Other than the missing quotation marks and the trailing comma, you seems to have an extra `}` in the last row.

Your code should look like this:

```
as.controller('Marketing', function ($scope, $http, $upload) {
  $scope.url = "partials/result.php";   //php-filen
  $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
    var file = $files[0];
    if (file.type.indexOf('image') == -1) {
      $scope.error = 'image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.'
    }
    if (file.size > 2097152) {
      $scope.error = 'File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
    }
    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
      url: "upload.php",
      data: {fname: $scope.fname},
      file: file,
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // file is uploaded successfully
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```